# Gostaria de contar uma lista de palavras em um arquivo.txt usando python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho esse código que conta o número de ocorrências de uma string em um arquivo.txt e me retorna. Mas gostaria de usar uma lista de itens ou um array. E que ele me retornasse a ocorrência de cada um desses itens. O código atual é esse:

```
 word = "12510537019"

 def counting(Text_File, Word):

    Data = open(Text_File, "r").read()

    count = Data.count(Word)

    print(Word, ":", count)

counting("arquivo.txt", word)
```

Mas gostaria de iniciar com algo assim:

```
word = [
    "12510537019",
    "21185356784",
    "22097245854",
    "16427169000",
    "12464413424",
    "13506742816",
    "11990657689"]
```

Como fazer?

Comment: O que você quer é contar a frequência de cada palavra em um texto a partir de uma lista de palavras? Ou seja, a quantidade de cada palavra da lista no texto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode experimentar usar [compreensão de listas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista):

```
wordList = [
    "12510537019",
    "21185356784",
    "22097245854",
    "16427169000",
    "12464413424",
    "13506742816",
    "11990657689"]

ocorrencias = [counting("arquivo.txt", word) for word in wordList]
```

Isso irá gerar uma nova lista com as ocorrências de cada palavra no arquivo:

```
print(ocorrencias)
#[3,6,2,1,9,8,7]
```

Tenha em mente que essa é a maneira mais rápida de fazer, porém não é a mais eficiente. O que isso faz é re-chamar a função `counting` para cada palavra da lista, fazendo o arquivo ser aberto e fechado múltiplas vezes. Para um exemplo de aprendizado ou algo pequeno acredito não ter problemas.

Comment: Okay, então qual seria a forma mais eficiente?

Comment: Perguntei acima sobre qual seria a forma mais eficiente porque quero aprendê-la! Se puder me ensinar serei grato!

Comment: @83HappyDog. Perdão, não tinha lido. Quando escrevi a resposta estava me referindo ao abrir o arquivo apenas uma vez, contar tudo que é necessário, e retornar. Pra isso você teria que modificar um pouco a função interna, ao invés de chamá-la várias vezes. Acredito que ela também não deveria imprimir nada dentro dela, apenas no programa principal. A mesma estrutura de compreensão de listas pode ser usada dentro da função, pra usar a função count para todos os elementos da lista.

Comment: Okay. Mas como eu poderia fazer isso na prática? Poderia usar ```map()``` ou nesse caso não se aplica?

Comment: Compartilhamos a mesma ideia sobre abrir o arquivo apenas uma vez e contar tudo que é necessário. Mas é neste ponto que estou me perdendo. Por isso perguntei acima, sobre como promover essas mudanças na prática?